# Why my token-pasting usage doesn't work?

Tags: c++

I made the declaration as below.

```
#define FUNC_DEC(f) inline void f##(){}

class MyClass
{
public:
    FUNC_DEC(a);
    FUNC_DEC(b);
};
```

After preprocessing, I expected the class looked like:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    inline void a(){};
    inline void b(){};
};
```

While actually, I got compiling errors

```
#20 identifier "a" is undefined
#20 identifier "b" is undefined

warnings
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
#891-D omission of explicit type is nonstandard ("int" assumed)
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my declaration? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please **do not do this.**

Comment: @bubble because it's bad style. Macros decrease readability if abused. `inline void fa() {}` is obvious, `FUNC_DEC(a)` isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to use the `##` operator.

```
#define FUNC_DEC(f) inline void f(){}
```

is fine.

It is concatenation operator, it useful for this kind of case:

```
#define FUNC_DEC(f) inline void FuncDec##f(){}
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Who will be expanded as:

```
inline void FuncDeca(){}   // FUNC_DEC(a)
```

*Just to say: Your code works fine on Visual Studio.*

Comment: @user2744038 How do you use your class? I mean, it should work. The error should be elsewhere. Look at this example: http://ideone.com/RKWrYA.

Comment: just created an instance and invoked the two interfaces.

Comment: Is this issue compiler specific? Does the warning hint something?

Comment: @user2744038 No. But do you have many files? Like the call in main.cpp, the class declaration in myclass.h and the class definition in myclass.cpp ?

Comment: Finally I got the root cause. As Pierre said, the error was somewhere else. Thank you Pierre.

Comment: @user2744038 Just being curious, but where was the error ? :)

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you don't need "token pasting". That is only useful if you have something like this:

```
#define FUNC_DEC(f) inline void func##f(){}
```

where you expect

```
inline void funca() {}
```

Comment: +1 - in fact, it gives an invalid preprocessing token in OP's case.  Clang says: `error: pasting formed 'a(', an invalid preprocessing token` and GCC says `error: pasting "a" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token`.

Comment: Might be helpful for extra clarity to show the #define that should be used to get the intended effect.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to parameterize the function name. How can I do that?

Comment: @user2744038 Just remove the '##' characters.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a macro with arguments

```
#define macro(X)
```

the uses of those arguments in the macro definition will be substituted with the inputs.

```
#define macro(X) void X() {}
macro(foo) // becomes void foo() {}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

The problem is that sometimes you want an argument as a part of a token, e.g. if you want to have macro that makes functions called GET_XXX; you need a way to tell the tokenizer to join the argument to the previous symbol. This is when you use pasting.

```
#define getfn(X) void get_##X() {} // '##X' is replaced with the value of X.

macro(foo) // becomes void get_foo() {}

int main() { get_foo(); }
```

If we had written

```
#define getfn(X) void get_X() {}
```

the compiler would have thought the 'X' was part of of a single literal string, get_X.